# Xpath != vs not

Tags: xml, xpath

Can somebody please explain if these two Xpath expressions are equivalent and why ?

```
$location!="work" 
not($location="work")
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [W3.org spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#booleans)

> NOTE: If $x is bound to a node-set, then $x="foo" does not mean the same as not($x!="foo"): the former is true if and only if some node in $x has the string-value foo; the latter is true if and only if all nodes in $x have the string-value foo.

This would lead me to believe that if $location is bound to a node-set, then  `$location != "work"` is true if any node is not "work", however, `not($location="work")` would be true only if **all** nodes are not "work".

Comment: The most common and obvious case where they are different is if $location is an empty sequence. In this case not($location="x") is true, while $location!="x" is false.